# Whats the cause of System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: on MongoDB on high load

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, sitecore

I have an application running on sitecore 7.5 with mongo(3 servers on Replica Set) and whenever during high load, mongo is not responding and I get the following error.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond      xx.xx.xx.xxx:27017

Sample stack trace
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,     SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open()
at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId)
at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message)
at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, IBsonSerializer resultSerializer, IBsonSerializationOptions resultSerializationOptions)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery query, IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, IMongoFields fields, Boolean returnNew, Boolean upsert)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery query, IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, Boolean returnNew, Boolean upsert)
at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(String application, String id, SessionStateLockCookie lockCookie, Int32& flags)
at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.SimpleMongoSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(String application, String id, SessionStateLockCookie lockCookie, Int32& flags)
at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&     completedSynchronously)
```

Has anyone encountered this before and anyone have any suggestions/ideas on where to look at?

Comment: I see that you're using MongoDB as your session store. Why would you replicate your session database? This will naturally decrease performance, and I don't think there's much of an upside to this.

Comment: I'm using mongo to maintain session state and to cache some info. I have 3 servers on three availability zones to make sure they are available all time.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running? We had performance issues with 2.6 recently under load, upgrading to 3.2 has helped.

Comment: 2.6.12. Are you on sitecore 7.5 as well coz I'm wondering upgrading mongo may cause issues with sitecore.